# Вывод всех месяцев с конкретного по текущей

Tags: дата, php

Здравствуйте,

Нужно вывести все месяцы(Месяц Год) до текущего на php
например задаю ноябрь 2013 он должен вывести:
ноябрь 2013
декабрь 2013
январь 2013

Собственно вопрос, как это реализовать?

P.s. это нужно для выборки из базы за конкретный месяц

Comment: получить метку времени;
    пока месяц(метка времени) < текущего месяца {
       вывести месяц;
       метка времени += количество секунд в месяце;
    }

Comment: @ua6xh нет такой штуки "количество секунд в месяце" но есть [DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php) (+1 month)

Comment: но есть такая штука "addMonth" (все конечно сильно зависит от используемого набора функций"

Comment: А также проверить или заданная дата случайно не больше текущей :)